# How to give the URL to the image file for automatic download?

Tags: html, image, url, automation, download

I have an image file and how do I generate or extract the URL to download it automatically?

So how to create a URL to auto-download image? I want the image to be downloaded as soon as the URL is clicked

Answer (score 1):

To provide a link for automatic download of an image file in HTML, you can use the download attribute along with an  (anchor) element. Here's an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Download Link</title>
</head>

<body>

    <a href="path/to/your/image.jpg" download="image.jpg">
        <img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="Image">
    </a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the URL of the image file, you can create a download link by wrapping it in an anchor tag ( element) and using the download attribute. Set the download attribute value to the desired filename for the downloaded image.

```
<a href="URL_OF_IMAGE" download="FILENAME">Click here to download the image</a>
```

When the user clicks on the link, the image file will be automatically downloaded to their device with the specified filename.